# MVC without framework?

Tags: javascript, php, model-view-controller

Now I don't have any specific question, rather a general, ask for opinions post.

Within a month we will receive the documentation of a project we have to develop. The website has a lot of potential and will be advertised in TV and radio as well when it'll be done. So it'll have a lot of visitors, members and it'll have a rich admin panel with lots of options. My friend who was asked to be the CTO is a senior PHP developer with almost 10 years of experience and I am a junior JS developer. (or less, I don't have years of experiences in JS, but I'm committed)

Is a JS MVC framework substitute for PHP? Is a PHP MVC framework substitute for JS? Are they both working well together or **is it possible to not use any framework, but write the project in MVC approach?**

*For example:*

- model: PHP
- controller: JS (jQuery+Ajax)
- view: HTML, CSS

As my friend is a professional PHP developer and will have a daily job next to, but only in the beginning of this project, he doesn't really want to learn an other language (like Node.js), because almost everything is a routine for him now in PHP.

I know everything depends on the documentation and what we have to develop exactly, but I'm just a curious mind and want to understand more. I know I have much to make up and sometimes I worry of my current knowledge, but then I think that **be whatever big the challenge, there will always be a solution for it.**

Comment: I think you are at **wrong** place. Ask this question on StackExchange's programmers site

Comment: I think what Lal means is that questions that seek views and opinions are not such a good fit here, which is for specific programming questions. But, you may get some thoughts in the comments.

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't know it! :) I got it, I'll look for what StackExchange is.

Comment: I think you need to decide what sort of application you want to build. I tend to see JavaScript MVC frameworks as being very useful for single-page apps, so if you want that, going down the JavaScript route (on the client side) is a good idea. But if you want to write a traditional app, then PHP/MVC is fine, and yes, you can do it without a "proper" framework. I regard DIY frameworks as a false economy in the long run - established ones are generally better tested and written than anything most people can come up with.

Comment: MVC is basically just a best-practices-common-sense separation of responsibilities inside your application. It's a way to structure your code. It has no influence over PHP/JS interaction/compatibility. As such: yes, PHP and JS will work together exactly the same no matter what structure you use; no, you don't need a framework to do any of this. Frameworks are also just code, prefabbed code in this case. You can write it yourself too.

Comment: If you have a strong PHP developer then I think you should work to your strengths and do most of the work in PHP. You can build and learn JS as you go along but you don't want to make the project JS-heavy and put pressure on yourself to deliver when you have a guy who can do it on the server-side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVC does not mean to use differenct languages for all of the modules (model, view, controller), but to loose couple and encapsulate certain parts of your application.

Against many opinions, MVC is not the panacea for application development. It really depends on the application you're developing.

It's not necessary to use any frameworks in order to follow the MVC approach. In fact it's a pattern that can be tied together very quickly, in it's most basic form.

If you decide to use your backend as an API and pull the data via frontend, you don't need to use MVC come hell or high water. For an API for example it's not necessary to perform most of the view tasks. Instead you should care about building a performant and scalable data storage layer (which for example is able to easily provide your data in many common formats, such as XML or JSON) and a strong router that can handle HTTP Requests nicely (See if REST is something for you).

In this case you want a strong frontend which can handle templates, and also has a strong layer for obtaining, sending and handling data in general. A strong controller layer that can delegate tasks to certain parts of your application would also come in handy.

Well you see what I'm talking about. It really depends on your application. In my example the backend wouldn't exactly follow the MVC approach, while my frontend would completely. MVC isn't about switching programming languages for certain parts of your application. Instead it decouples your application structure making things a lot easier.

Of course Frameworks come in handy when developing such an enterprise scale application, but it's not necessarily required.

To sum things up: MVC has not much to do with the code itself, it has much more to do with architecture and structure of your code. How exactely you're implementing it is absolutely up to you.